# Determinant of real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix such that every entry at the main diagonal is positive, the other entries are negative, and the sum of all entries in each row is $1$. Show that the determinant of $A$ is greater than $1$.

Comment: Do you have thoughts on the problem and can share them so responders can provide better guidance? ALso, if this is HW, it should be marked as such. Regards

Comment: The one-by-one matrix $1$ satisfies the conditions and does not have determinant greater than $1$

Comment: this is a problem of a mathematics contest in my regional, I don't have any idea to solve this problem

Comment: Yoshua - If this is an *ongoing* (current) contest, then it is not appropriate to post it here until the contest is over.